# Sending mail with template using zeptomail of zoho crm

Tags: node.js, email, zoho, zeptomail

Actually I am trying to send the email with ZeptoMail .
I had created one template .

i.e.

```
<html>
<body>{{name}}</body>
</html>
```

And I am using the zepto email sending api .

```
const axios = require('axios');
let data = JSON.stringify({
  "from": {
    "address": "abc@abc.com",
    "name": "Paula"
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "email_address": {
        "address": "abc@abc.com",
        "name": "Abc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "subject": "Hi",
  "template_key": "my_template_key"
});

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.zeptomail.com/v1.1/email/template',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'my_token', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  },
  data : data
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

But need to also send the "name" which is act like a variable in my template.
how can I send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `"merge_info"` key in the request body.

Add all your variables under this key.

Reference: [Documentation of API](https://www.zoho.com/zeptomail/help/api/email-templates.html)

Example (in Single Email Template): In this case, all variables are common.

```js
let data = JSON.stringify({
  "from": {
    "address": "abc@abc.com",
    "name": "Paula"
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "email_address": {
        "address": "abc@abc.com",
        "name": "Abc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "subject": "Hi",
  "template_key": "my_template_key",
  "merge_info": {
    "name": "Guest",
    ...other_variables_here 
  }
});
```

Example (in Multiple Email Template): In this case, some variables differs for each email.

```js
let data = JSON.stringify({
  "from": {
    "address": "abc@abc.com",
    "name": "Paula"
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "email_address": {
        "address": "abc@abc.com",
        "name": "Abc"
      },
      "merge_info": {
         "name": "Abc",
         ...other_variables_here 
      }
    },
    {
      "email_address": {
        "address": "def@abc.com",
        "name": "Def"
      },
      "merge_info": {
         "name": "Def",
         ...other_variables_here 
      }
    }

  ],
  "subject": "Hi",
  "template_key": "my_template_key",
});
```